# How to auto create columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df['2 Min']=df['Close'].shift(-1)-df['Open']
df['3 Min']=df['Close'].shift(-2)-df['Open']
df['4 Min']=df['Close'].shift(-3)-df['Open']
df['5 Min']=df['Close'].shift(-4)-df['Open']
```

Im trying to figure out a quick way to continue this pattern to a specified number without having to write them individually. I'm thinking possibly a for loop, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check with for loop

```
for x in range(-4,-1+1):

    df[str(abs(x)) + ' Min'] = df['Close'].shift(x)-df['Open']
```

Comment: Thaank you so much! I was wondering if there was also a way to change the the column name with the same code? I don't know how to place a variable in to a column name change.